# converting an .obj file into .pdf3D in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I wish that somebody could help me solving this problem.
I want to convert an *.obj file into pdf3D using Java. I have tried using the library [itextpdf](https://itextpdf.com/) (at the end you can find the code that I used), but I just managed to convert a u3D file to pdf. Do I have to change something in the code or should I use another library?

```
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class Main
{
public static String RESOURCE = "C:\\Users\\bb\\IdeaProjects/Zuccarello.U3D";
public static String RESULT="C:\\Users\\bb\\IdeaProjects/obj.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    new Main().createPdf ( RESULT);
}

public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 400, 500, 800);
    rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
    rect.setBorderWidth(0.5f);
    rect.setBorderColor(new BaseColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));
    document.add(rect);

    PdfStream  stream3D = new PdfStream(new FileInputStream(RESOURCE), writer);
    stream3D.put(PdfName.TYPE, new PdfName("3D"));
    stream3D.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName("U3D"));
    stream3D.flateCompress();
    PdfIndirectObject streamObject = writer.addToBody(stream3D);
    stream3D.writeLength();

    PdfDictionary dict3D = new PdfDictionary();
    dict3D.put(PdfName.TYPE, new PdfName("3DView"));
    dict3D.put(new PdfName("XN"), new PdfString("Default"));
    dict3D.put(new PdfName("IN"), new PdfString("Unnamed"));
    dict3D.put(new PdfName("MS"), PdfName.M);
    dict3D.put(new PdfName("C2W"),
            new PdfArray(new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 3, -235, 28 } ));
    dict3D.put(PdfName.CO, new PdfNumber(235));

    PdfIndirectObject dictObject = writer.addToBody(dict3D);

    PdfAnnotation annot = new PdfAnnotation(writer, rect);
    annot.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString("3D Model"));
    annot.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName("3D"));
    annot.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.ANNOT);
    annot.put(new PdfName("3DD"), streamObject.getIndirectReference());
    annot.put(new PdfName("3DV"), dictObject.getIndirectReference());
    PdfAppearance ap = writer.getDirectContent().createAppearance(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    annot.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, ap);
    annot.setPage();

    writer.addAnnotation(annot);
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3D PDF only supports .prc and .u3d files. [Direct file conversion formats adobe.com](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/supported-file-formats-acrobat-reader.html)
So you need to convert one of those first.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :),
Do you know any libraries in Java that allow me to create and export u3D files in Java?
I have already calculated the faces, vertices and Textures in Java and want to export them in a u3D file.

Comment: I did some Export to .prc once, using Hoops Exchange. I added them to a 3D pdf using Acrobat pro, but manually. 
I cannot find a free/open source solution. Paid solutions don't seem to be available in Java.

Comment: @KYL3R For the same type of conversion do you have any solutions other than java. And my requirement is I have one .obj file I need to convert the file in .pdf file.

Comment: @Bhavanaditya: A single file, once? If the online converters (google 'obj to prc') won't work you can upload the obj somewhere and I will convert it for you.

Comment: @KYL3R I have multiple and multiple .obj files need to convert it .pdf files. Is there any possibilities. If available means please help with this. And thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Bhavanaditya, I am working on the same problem, can you kindly help me with this? how did you convert obj to u3d and added it to PDF?

Comment: You can try converters like this one: https://products.aspose.app/3d/conversion/obj-to-u3d - to add it to a pdf file you need Acrobat Pro - simply drag it in.